# Value error: Setting an array element to sequence using numpy and Bessel functions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have been trying to solve a value error (setting array element to sequence) but anything I try wont correct the issue. The code revolves around using bessel functions of the first kind and comparing them against the `jv(v,z)` function but the line of `a[k] = B1(theta[k])` is causing my error. I have only been coding in Python 3 for about 6 weeks so I am still fairly new to this.

**EDITED INDENTATION**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pylab as plt
from numpy import pi
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import special
from numpy import cos
from numpy import sin

x = 1.0
def B1(theta):
  j1 = cos(theta-x*sin(theta))
  return (j1)

theta = np.linspace(0.0, 20.0, 1000)
a = np.linspace(0.0, 20.0, 1000)
b = a
r = np.linspace(0.0e-6, 1.0e-6, 1000)
x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 1000)
y = x
Ij = (1.0/pi)*integrate.simps(B1(theta), theta)

for k in range(0, len(theta)):
  if k>0: 
    a[k] = B1(theta[k])
    b[k] = scipy.special.jv(1, theta[k])
  else:
    a[k] = 1.0
    b[k] = 1.0
plt.plot(theta, a,'r-')
plt.plot(theta, b,'k-')
plt.show()
```

Any help by anyone would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling over this for several hours now.

Edit: For reference my trace log is as follows
       File "Ag1P1.py", line 32, in 
       a[k] = B1(theta[k])
       ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I think now my error lies in where I use  the following

```
     x = 1.0
    def B1(theta):
      j1 = cos(theta-x*sin(theta))
      return(j1)
```

I'm uncertain as to why but any values I input as such;

```
      a[k] = B1(theta[k])
```

produce this error. Yet I do not know of a solution to go about correcting this.

Comment: Posting the full traceback would help, but from the error it's apparent that you should check the lines where you set an array element (`a[k] =` and `b[k] =`). Check the RHS of these assignments to see if the expression is in fact a sequence (array) and not a number.

Comment: Why do you do `b = a`? Now `b` refers to the same object that `a` refers to. This is probably not the cause of your problem, but surely not what you intend to do.

Comment: It's just a personal preference with setting up a second array to be used in the program. It's worked for me in the past like that so I just stick with it.

Comment: @Krios101, you should not be doing that. Once you do `a[k] = something` and then `b[k] = something_else`, you are actually overwriting whatever you put into `a[k]`.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, Bessel functions are defined for positive parameters only. Perhaps you are passing a negative parameter causing a `ValueError`. I would suggest adding an assert like this as a means of debugging.

```
for k in range(0, len(theta)):
  if k>0: 
    assert theta[k] > 0
    a[k] = B1(theta[k])
    b[k] = scipy.special.jv(1, theta[k])
  else:
    a[k] = 1.0
    b[k] = 1.0
```

Also, you should post your stacktrace (what does the error say exactly) and this will help me and others debug.

Comment: Here is the traceback error I got from my terminal Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ag1P1.py", line 29, in <module>
    a[k] = B1(theta[k])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
I've tried printingt the value types before and when B1 is called at a[k] it stated the value returned (j1) was the array value which confused me earlier. And is the assert function similar to an exit condintion for the if statement?